# GitHub wiki relative links becoming img tags

Tags: github, github-flavored-markdown

Some relative links on my [GitHub wiki](https://github.com/oeed/Silica/wiki)'s pages and sidebar are appearing as img tags, rather than links, while others appear perfectly fine.

For example, the markdown for my sidebar is the following:

```
[[Home]]

[[Getting Started|Tutorial – Getting Started]]

[[Tutorials]]

[[Core Topics]]

[[Classes]]
```

I would expect that to create five links, but only the top two appear as links.

[image: img tags appearing instead of links]

The link of the img tag is the correct address to the page interestingly:

```
<img src="/oeed/Silica/wiki/Tutorials">
```

Some places where it had occurred before seem to have fixed themselves, but I can't seem to find any pattern.